# How do users amasse tens of thousands of reputation points?

Tags: discussion, reputation

I'll admit, I'm hooked on the gamification of Stack Overflow. I enjoy helping other devs by providing good answers to their questions, but I am motivated by seeing that green `+15`, and seeing the number by my name increase.

That being said, it can also be a bit **de**motivating to see users with tens of thousands of rep points. I mean, I work full time. I can't even imagine reaching that level by earning a meager 15-25 points here and there.

Are the users with 50k+ reputation score

1. Early adopters?
2. Answering bountied questions on the reg?
3. Putting in full-time hours on Stack Overflow?

Or are they taking advantage of some secret to amassing thousands of reputation points that I am just not aware of?

Essentially, my question boils down to this: How do I maximize (in terms of rep points) the limited time I have for participating on Stack Overflow.

Comment: Perform the actions that result in the most rep gain - answering questions. Some will give you rep, others won't, but if you aren't answering, you're not investing in the long-term rep gains of your account.

Comment: I'm not a 50k rep user so I cannot speak to that specifically, but answering questions is the key. The more you answer, the more rep you get, not to mention that it increases your odds of answering a question that becomes very popular, in which one good answer can net hundreds if not thousands of rep.

Comment: It's hard to gain 1k+ rep from a single post due to the daily rep caps, it's more important to have a whole lot of answers that will gain upvotes over time rather than one big influx of upvotes on a single post.

Comment: I outsourced everything ... even my Meta participation ...

Comment: @KevinB That's true, but on popular questions, the upvotes seem to trickle in for days/weeks. Having a few of these can certainly provide a  "steady income" :) Note that I do *not* disagree with your point about answering plenty of questions being more important.

Comment: Time, mostly. Write good answers, improve over time, make them as helpful as possible and just have patience. Eventually the focus on rep disappears and you just answer.

Comment: The most frustrating thing for me is when I spend the time to craft an answer, then the user comments "Thanks, this totally fixed my issue!" without upvoting or accepting my answer. I'm not in it for the "thanks"! lol

Comment: The most rep comes from answers that are useful to not just the op, but future visitors on questions that future visitors will be able to find. I'm still getting upvotes on answers from 6+ years ago

Comment: Have you tried posting good, well researched questions and answers? If you do that lots, you'll get lots of points.

Comment: My first 20k rep came very quickly, over the course of a year or so. After that, I became far less active due to the lack of a "goal" to go after. There were no new privileges to unlock. so, I transitioned to using the privileges I had unlocked and just allowed the rep to roll in from all of those answers i posted previously.

Comment: Thanks for the snark, @Richard. 

Comment: If someone comes up with a better solution, I'm all ears

Comment: Slow and steady wins the race. Answer what you can when you can. Bounty hunting on topics you have experience in helps. 2 - 4 good answers in a day coupled with passive votes can reach your daily cap most times. I started off just like you 4yrs ago and gradually answered what I knew. It also helped reinforce projects I was working on in work and in some cases helped me solve problems with projects while answering a question.

Comment: Also important is to learn when to take a step back. If too focused on not gaining rep on recent posts it can take its toll (so I'm told ;)). Taking a day or two away and return to potential votes helps re-motivate. And just because some questions already have answers does not mean that you can't improve on what is already there if you have a viable alternative.

Comment: Admittedly, after having been "hooked to the gamification" initially, I also thought: Well, I wrote a dozen answers now - now I can just sit there and watch my rep growing. Nope. However: Sometimes, there are low-hanging fruits: A simple answer can bring 100 upvotes in one week (particularly when it reaches the threshold to appear as "answer with extreme votes" in the 10k-tools), but then the Q/A is never seen again. Other answers are more "durable" and earn a "steady income" of 2-3 upvotes per week, over several years. So ... it depends.

Comment: Take Coldsp33d for exemple. Join the site in late 2017. Hit reputation cap every day. Get to 100k in less than 2 years.

Comment: Simple math: you've got ~100 answers and ~2K rep. I've got ~1000 answers and ~20K rep. It's all about putting in a _lot_ of good answers, our rep per answer is very much similar

Comment: I joined SE not to gain rep, but to help others (and get help, too). Reputation isn't really important to me; in fact, reputation would've been useless if there weren't privileges to unlock when reputation increased. To me, that number on the top-right corner of my screen is just an indicator of what the SE world thinks about my questions and answers.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

> Are the users with 50k+ reputation score
>
> ```
> Early adopters?
> Answering bountied questions on the reg?
> Putting in full-time hours on Stack Overflow?
> ```

It's a combination of all three. I know some users who have earned nearly 100,000 reputation in a year just by coming online and answering every question they can find about certain technologies. It helps that they are online looking for questions (or subscribed via an RSS feed) to answer the entire day.

As your answers age and start to grow in size, you'll start to receive lots of what we call "passive upvotes" (or the occasional passive downvote)... these are votes on old content that come in weeks, months, or years later, rather than coming in within the first few hours or days after you post a new answer. As your account gets older and your answer count grows, you're likely to start earning a majority of your reputation just from this. The users with 100k reputation often hit their reputation cap for the day without writing any new answers.

Additionally, users who posted answers in 2008, 2009, or 2010 (for example) have had a decade to receive the occasional upvote from their answers! That's a lot of drive-by traffic... they've had hundreds to thousands more opportunities to earn 200 reputation each day than you, after all.

The best way I can recommend for you to earn more reputation is by continuing to answer wherever you think you can provide a good, novel answer (be sure not to repeat existing answers) to a question. You can do this by answering in questions you're an expert in, answering questions that have active bounties, or answering in questions where you have to learn a new technology in order to provide an answer (this last one has the benefit of both teaching others and teaching yourself).

Keep in mind that you earn rep for upvotes on good questions, too, so don't be afraid to ask one if you've put a lot of effort into some task but are still stumped.

Comment: You're focusing a lot on the longer time that others have spent here. But there are other factors. It certainly depends on the tag. You'd rather earn 50k with JavaScript than with COBOL. And then there are "hype questions": As soon as a Q/A appears in the HNQ or the "extreme votes"-section of the 10k-tools, the upvotes can easily go hyperbolic. (I think that usually, answers that cause a steady stream upvotes are more valuable assets, but that's just MHO)

Comment: @Marco13 you are still capped to 200 points from votes, so a HNQ “hit” doesn’t get you more than a few hundred points. That’ll never get you to 50k, you can’t bank on finding more HNQ hits to get you there. It’s definitely the quality answers that get you the repeat votes long term; I hit the cap every day wether I write new answers or not. Good thing I’m not focused on rep gain ;-)

Comment: @MartijnPieters As long as it's not about blind "rep wh0ring", keeping an eye on the rep/upvoes is not a bad thing per se - it **is** feedback and an indicator how helpful answers are. This doesn't always align with the own perception... (I'm still somewhat embarrassed that https://stackoverflow.com/a/41348525/3182664 is still visible as a spike in my rep graph :-/ ). *Knowing* that an answer is good, but not receiving positive feedback, can be frustrating. As I said, there are many influencing factors (googleability, durability (jQuery anyone?), crosslinks/dupetargeting etc.)

Comment: @TylerH: Good post, though I think that getting upvotes for even clearly stated and well formatted questions is rather seldom.